# Python inverse endswith() method

Tags: python, inverse

I hava a very simple piece of code, similar to this:

```
if var1.endswith("/"):
    print("whatever")
```

What can I do to inverse the if, except using an else statement?
Like I want to print "whatever" if var1 does not end with "/"

Thanks,

Comment: `if not var1.endswith("/"):`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you could just `index` the last `char` of the `string`:

```
if var1[-1] != '/':
   print("whatever")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `not`

```
if not var1.endswith("/"):
    print("whatever")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not var1.endswith("/"):
    print("whatever")
```